# Create a property with predefined list of values C#

Tags: c#, class, properties

I'm trying to do something like this:

create some list of properties and values:

```
public class field_type
{
    public static string NUMBER = "NUMBER";
    public static string VARCHAR = "VARCHAR";
    public static string BOOLEAN = "BOOLEAN";
    public static string DATE = "DATE";
}
```

then use it as a type for another property:

```
public class field_definition
{
    public string field_name;
    public string field_description;
    public field_type field_type;                 <-- this one
    public string field_size;
    public bool primary_key;
    public bool auto_increment;
    public bool unsigned;
    public string default_value;
    public bool can_be_null;
}
```

then use it like this:

```
List<field_definition> field_defs1 = new List<field_definition>();
field_defs1.Add(new field_definition
{
    field_type = 

});
```

The point is when I hit space after equal symbol intellisense shows me the list of available values for this property, like it happens in VBA, is it possible?

Comment: It is a bit hard to understand what you mean here. `field_type` can only hold an instance of the `field_type` class, not strings, you sure you're not looking for an enum instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use an enum?

```
enum field_type { NUMBER, VARCHAR, BOOLEAN, DATE };
List<field_definition> field_defs1 = new List<field_definition>();
field_defs1.Add(new field_definition
{
    field_type = field_type.NUMBER;

});
```

Comment: Where does he specified that he needs a string?

Comment: I see myself that they are string. My suggestion was for using another approach. This is for the reason he doesn't specified that what he needs is a String. Why  all this polemics?

Comment: True, I've erased my comments, misread your answer sorry. It still doesn't exactly solve the question the OP is asking; intellisense *will* default to `field_type` but you still need to type `field_type.` before available values show up. OP is asking if its possible that values show up after typing `=`.

Comment: Haven't used to enums yet, thank you)) I'm wondering now if i can specify something that is not in the list))

Answer (score 0):

just for your interest: you should not use a classname as object name:`public field_type field_type;`

Solution:

```
  List<field_definition> field_defs1 = new List<field_definition>();
field_defs1.Add(new field_definition()
{
    auto_increment= true,
    field_name = "lala",  ... etc

});
```

You just forgot the round brackets from the constructor call :)

Comment: in what way does this answer the OP's question?

Comment: OP'S question:
"The point is when I hit space after equal symbol intellisense shows me the list of available values for this property, like it happens in VBA, is it possible?"

This happens when the Syntax is correct ...

Comment: Yes, it does.
I tested it myself before i send this post !

Comment: You are misunderstanding the OP's question completely; when typing any statement of the type `MyType myVariable =` intellisense wll *most definitely* not prompt you with available static values defined in `MyType` automatically. I have no idea where you got that idea from. And that is precisely what the OP is asking for.

Comment: It wont even do that for `enums` which is the closest you can get to the behavior the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

You code will not work like this.

You can only access to the properties of your field_type class, like field_type.NUMBER.
But you precise that this properties are static, so you cannot change them.

If you want to store a type that always match your values in field_type class, i assume that your code will be like that  :

This class will store the different value of your field_type, only store.

```
public static class field_type
    {
        public static string NUMBER = "NUMBER";
        public static string VARCHAR = "VARCHAR";
        public static string BOOLEAN = "BOOLEAN";
        public static string DATE = "DATE";
    }
```

Your field_type here is a string :

```
 public class field_definition
    {
        public string field_name;
        public string field_description;
        public string field_type;
        public string field_size;
        public bool primary_key;
        public bool auto_increment;
        public bool unsigned;
        public string default_value;
        public bool can_be_null;
    }
```

And you can use it like this :

```
List<field_definition> field_defs1 = new List<field_definition>();
        field_defs1.Add(new field_definition
        {
            field_type = field_type.NUMBER
        });
```

Or `field_type=field_type.DATE` or all your values in the field_type class.

Answer (score 0):

Where to start?

When you type `field_type =` and you hit space, what is the compiler expecting? Well, the answer is... about anything; all these are valid options:

```
field_type = null;
field_type = new field_type();
field_type = myFieldTypeVariableDeclaredBeforeInMyCode;
field_type = 1;
field_type = dlñfjasfjoafja;
field_type = field_type.NUMBER;
```

*All* are valid options. Obviously *some* are compile time errors.

Curiously you seem to want the last option: `field_type = field_type.NUMBER` which is obviously wrong. You are asking intellisense to prompt you with an illegal assigment; assigning a `string` to a `field_type` typed variable.

But forget that, there is a bigger issue that prevents intellisense from behaving the way you seem to want. `NUMBER`, `BOOLEAN`, etc. are names that only make sense inside the class `field_type`. Outside the class definition they mean nothing, therefore you *need to qualify* the name to make sure the compiler undertands it. How? Typing `field_type.`: `field_type = field_type.NUMBER;`. Now `field_type.NUMBER` is fully qualified and the compiler can understand what `NUMBER` is: the string `"NUMBER"`.

Do notice that when you hit `.` *after* typing `field_type` the compiler *will* happily show you all the available options. That is because it is now 100% sure that there are no other possible options available to you.

But the compiler will *not* prompt you with any possible values after typing `=` becuase it doesn't have enough information to make an educated guess of what comes next: again, all these are legal:

```
field_type = null;
field_type = new field_type();
field_type = myFieldTypeVariableDeclaredBeforeInMyCode;
field_type = field_type.//whatever;
```

Why should it decide `field_type.` is the best option?

The closest you can get to the desired behavior is using [enums](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx). In that case intellisense at least will default to the enum type because chances are very very high that that is precisely what comes next.